# An indefinite article with a plural head noun

Tags: articles, modifiers

I am working on the Reading Test of the Barron's SAT Practice Test 1 - "Indian Country" by Peter Matthiessen, and there is a sentence on line 18 "*Termination legislation, which had already wiped out a small number of small tribes, not only withdraws all federal aid, but turns he Indians over to the mercies of state jurisdiction and poverty taxation, forcing **a people** with no other recourse to put their last resource - land - upon the market.*"

So the question is why the author uses the indefinite article with a plural head noun?

I searched the use of article in numerous sources, but none refers to such a case.

P.S. Please, do not vote to close this topic because you believe that such a case does not exist. I have seen a closed post on a similar question, and sadly, the question was closed.

Thanks for cooperation!

Comment: This [has been asked on ELU,](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/448184/) where the accepted answer cites [dictionary.com definition #2](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/people) *the entire body of persons who constitute a community, tribe, nation, or other group by virtue of a common culture, history, religion, or the like*. The cited context lumps all surviving Indian tribes together as members of ***one single** nation or group*.

Answer (score 3):

One of the meanings of *people* is *the members of a particular nation, community, or ethnic group*. It's perfectly correct to say *a people* in this context, just as we say *a nation.*

Answer (score 2):

"A people" is a very common way of referring to *a specific group* of people.

It is a particularly useful term when referring to a group that may be harder to define - in this case, it is not a whole nation, nor a single tribe, but a group of tribes commonly affected by something.

Answer (score 1):

The word *people* in that sense is singular, and "a people" is correct.
The sense is referring to a group of individuals with nationality or ethnicity in common.
It can even be pluralized: *the peoples of Europe*, an example that appears in this discussion:
[Stack Exchange English Language & Usage *people are/is*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/263046/people-are-is-which-one-is-correct)
(in the last answer)

Comment: Now it is clear: thanks to all of you who have contributed!